# Flutter sqflite error SqfliteDatabaseExceptions

Tags: flutter, sqflite

The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.1.

Because finaltodolist depends on sqflite >=2.3.0-0 which requires SDK version >=3.0.0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
"FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\src\flutter",
"PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
"PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\piyus\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1

HOW TO SOVE THIS PROBLEM

Comment: Error message is clear: Update the sdk requirements in pub.xml.